# Underscore where es6/typescript alternative

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there alternative for underscore method (where) ?

I would like to find an array with some properties like here:

```
_.where(listOfPlays, {author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611});
=> [{title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611},
```

Comment: I mean, you can write one if you want.  What have you tried?

Comment: like how to code it without underscore? That would be filter, if you want to be able to pass in any object and look for a match you would need to use every also

Comment: I'm looking for build in method like this, where i could describe part of the object

Comment: There is nothing that does exactly that, you would have to code it and it is just a couple of lines

Comment: All right ;/ . I will have to add my own into array.prototype . Thx

Comment: Like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwBYFMBO6A8AVAPgAoBDTTALkTwG0BdAGkQAcqAFM2EgG3wIEoqtOogDeAKESJsUEJiRlMAOmAxuULEQBuiALwFERAPIAjAFbpoSgNboAngGcizfohIPEAQXIk7OW3ZwwNQCSuhaWHZE1noGWjTWIrrJLAl0-PwA3OIAvuIQCA5QiNwwRUbAbNy+HrqINJJiiLBQ3OhUAEQAwnYAtibopWDoHUwkIFCocJSIHQDKqCS2DszoZCNMdmszAIwAbDs7iDkMjaLNMK3tswBKcL3ocG5gACaIAFIgpehQo24TUxm80Wy1W6z+WzIVB2AFYAJww46nKTnFptTp4DCIADicG4L3QSE8AHMNv9JtNOgAJezIOBwF4Q7bQg5HPJ0fKFPHoJTcODEohoLDoIilcqVaqOJjncYUoELJboFbbMmQ3as44ZbIAem1+nqqMu6NmPX6gxgwz+ssBnQVoJVTKhiH2hyRQA)?

Comment: It's [considered bad practice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes) to extend native prototypes like you're suggesting

Comment: @jcalz `Object.keys(p)` should be cached, you don't need to call it for every item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter`. You won't be able to use an object but you can use properties directly:

```
let results = listOfPlays.filter(play => play.author === "Shakespeare" && play.year === 1611);
```

Alternatively, if you actualy want a replica of `_.where`:

```
function where(array, object) {
  let keys = Object.keys(object);
  return array.filter(item => keys.every(key => item[key] === object[key]));
}
```

`where` filters objects from `array` that match every key-value from the object `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Basic concept of Array.filter, Array.each, and Object.entries

```js
var plays = [
  { title: "world", author: "hello", year: 1611 },
  { title: "Cymbeline", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611 },
  { title: "Bacon", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611 },
  { title: "Dance", author: "Shakespeare", year: 1610 }
]


const getResults = (plays, filters) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(filters)
  return result = plays.filter( play => {
    return entries.every(([key, value]) => {
      return play[key] === value
    })
  })
}

var testOne = getResults(plays, {
  author: "Shakespeare", year: 1611
})

var testTwo = getResults(plays, {
  year: 1611
})

console.log(testOne)
console.log(testTwo)
```